# MuleSoft - Running Batch job using XML array

Tags: mule4

I am trying to run a Batch Job using XML array. My XML structure looks like below.

```
<file>
  <data>
    <deliveryOrder>
      <deliveryMethod>TRUCK1</deliveryMethod>
    </deliveryOrder>
    <deliveryOrder>
      <deliveryMethod>TRUCK21</deliveryMethod>
    </deliveryOrder>
    <deliveryOrder>
      <deliveryMethod>TRUCK2</deliveryMethod>
    </deliveryOrder>
  </data>
</file>
```

At the moment my batch step only runs once with entire xml. My requirement is to run batch-step for each 'deliveryOrder'. One solution is to convert it to JSON, which works fine. However, I don't want to do that since target systems use xml interface.

Please advice if there is a way to run batch on XML items directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Batch doesn't know about JSON or XML, it knows about consuming iterable inputs. JSON has the concept of arrays and probably that's the reason it works. XML has no concept of arrays. It has nested elements, that some implementations might treat as an array. Converting XML to JSON just for batch processing is very inefficient, as the payload will need to be parsed and transformed to the internal representation twice.

One alternative is to just use DataWeave to transform to a Java array of the elements to process:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.file.data.*deliveryOrder
```

This returns an array of all deliverOrder elements under file.data.